# How to filter out common keys of 2 different maps in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, filter, collections, tuples

I want to retrieve the key, value of a list/array (assume A) which the key exists in another list/array (assume B)

```
val B: List[String] = List("key1","key3")  //I can refactor the type if needed

val paramNames: Array[String] = parameterNames  // ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
val paramValues: Array[AnyRef] = args //  [1, "value", Obj]

val A: Array[(String,AnyRef)] = paramNames.zip(paramValues) //  [("key1", 1), ("key2", "value"), ("key3", Obj)]

//now I want to retrieve from A, all keys exist in B with their values
//to get [("key1", 1), ("key3", Obj)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use filter:

```
val C = A.filter(k => B.contains(k._1))
```

This will get only tuples, whose keys are contained in `B`.

Comment: Note that you might want to convert B to a set first to improve performance.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be better, Thanks a lot for helping :)